# Laravel route (voyager and others) shows 404

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, laravel

I Use Apache 2.4.41, on WSL2/Ubuntu.
There I have a laravel project, with Voyager installed.
I also use a virtualhost(vh) for it.

Accessing the App url `http://myapp` works.
However - The Voyager app at `http://myapp/admin` fails with 404 error.

My `VirtualHost` file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myapp

    DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp/public


    <Directory "/var/www/myapp/public">
        Options Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>



    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My `.htaccess` file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DocumentRoot is /var/www/myapp/public.

Is the admin under that path? If not, then you need to define an Alias for it in the Apache configuration:

```
Alias /path/to/admin "/var/www/myapp/public/admin"
```

If it is already under the public path, I would double check the Apache logs and the Linux permissions assigned to the admin page.